# If $f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ is differentiable at $c \in [a,b]$ s.t. $f'(c) \neq 0$ then $\frac{1}{f}$ is differentiable at $c$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I need to just prove that the function $1/f$ is differentiable at $c$ using the following lemma:

> If $\exists$ a function $F$ s.t.
>
> (1) $F$ is continuous at $0$,
>
> (2) $f(c+h) = f(c) + hF(h)$ for all sufficiently small $h$.
>
> Then $f$ is differentiable at $c$ and $F(0) = f'(c)$.

So I would like to find such a function. Here is my incomplete attempt so far:

If $f(x)$ is differentiable at $c$ then it is continuous at $c$. Then $1/f(x)$ is also continuous at c. Consider the function $F$ s.t.

$\frac{1}{f(h+c)} = \frac{1}{f(c)} + h F(h)$

Then $F$ satisfies (2) from the lemma.

Now I would like to show $F$ satisfies (1) and that is where I need help.

First of all how do I go about proving $F$ is continuous at $0$?

Second of all, I am confused about the lemma itself. It says $F$ needs to be continuous at $0$ but $0$ is not in the domain of $F$. Then what am I missing here?

Third of all, what is this lemma called? Where can I read more about it? I learned of this lemma in Richard Goldber's book "Methods of Real Analysis" page 195.

Comment: This is not a famous lemma but rather a tactical device employed by your book author. Nothing special about it. You can instead relax first condition to the existence of $\lim_{h\to 0} F(h) =L$ and then the desired derivative is $L$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since posting this I went back to my notebook and realized a few things. Below is my proof for $F$ being continuous at $0$.

Since $f$ is differentiable at $c$ then by the lemma, $\exists$ a function $G$ s.t. it satisfies both (1) and (2). So,

$f(c+h) = f(c) + h G(h)$.

Now consider the function $F$ defined for the same $h$ as $G$:

$\frac{1}{f(h+c)} = \frac{1}{f(c)} + h F(h)$

We would like to show $F$ is continuous at $0$.

$F(h) = \frac{\frac{1}{f(c+h)}-\frac{1}{f(c)}}{h}$
$=-\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{hf(c)f(c+h)}=-\frac{G(h)}{f(c)f(c+h)}$

For a fixed $c$, $f(c) \neq 0$ is constant and $f(c+h)$ is continuous at $c$. We already know $G$ is continuous at $0$, so $F$ is continuous at $0$ as well.

Hence, by the lemma $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is differentiable at $c$ and $F(0) = f'(c)$.

Comment: Apart from minor typos (fix it by writing  $f(c+h) $ is continuous at $0$ and at the end $F(0)=(1/f)'(c)$) this is correct. +1

Answer (score 0):

$f(c)\ne 0$, otherwise 1/f(c) not defined.
Rest is straightforward from the definition of derivative.

Comment: Right.  The statement as-is would say: since $f(x) = x$ has derivative $f'(0)=1 \ne 0$, then $1/x$ is differentiable at $0$.